# Getting JSON $_POST from FoxyCart Order Desk

Tags: php, json, post, foxycart

I am trying to create a script to receive POST from FoxyCart's Order Desk. I setup a temporary request bin at requestb.in. When I pointed the POST there I get the new order JSON fine. I copy/pasted the JSON string in my script with this code I was able to parse the JSON and successfully added the variables to my database:

```
$string = "{"id":"1191583","email":"office@burntimpressions.com","shipping_method":"","quantity_total":1,"weight_total":0,"product_total":0,"shipping_total":0,"handling_total":0,"tax_total":0,"discount_total":0,"order_total":0,"cc_number_masked":"","cc_exp":"","processor_response":"","payment_type":"","payment_status":"Approved","processor_balance":0,"customer_id":"","email_count":"1","ip_address":"71.161.83.59","tag_color":"","source_name":"Order Desk","source_id":"1191583","fulfillment_name":"","fulfillment_id":"","tag_name":"","folder_id":6814,"date_added":"2015-06-14 16:53:54","date_updated":"2015-06-14 16:54:27","shipping":{"first_name":"Galen","last_name":"Dively","company":"Vermont Novelty Toaster Corporation","address1":"136 Bay Street","address2":"Ste 2","address3":"","address4":"","city":"Saint Johnsbury","state":"Vermont","postal_code":"05819","country":"US","phone":"(916) 448-5517"},"customer":{"first_name":"Galen","last_name":"Dively","company":"Vermont Novelty Toaster Corporation","address1":"136 Bay Street","address2":"Ste 2","city":"Saint Johnsbury","state":"Vermont","postal_code":"05819","country":"US","phone":"(916) 448-5517"},"checkout_data":[],"order_metadata":[],"discount_list":[],"order_notes":[],"order_items":[{"id":"2090400","name":"selfie test","price":0,"quantity":1,"weight":0,"code":"selfie","delivery_type":"ship","category_code":"","variation_list":[],"metadata":[]}],"order_shipments":[]}";
$order = json_decode($string, true);
$transactionId = $order [id];
$firstName = $order[customer][first_name];
foreach($order [order_items] as $p)
{
$cid = $p[id];
$productName = $p[name];
$code = $p[code];
$quantity = $p[quantity];
}
```

Order Desk's documentation says to get the POST with this:

```
$order = json_decode($_POST['order'], 1);
```

I am not getting anything. I have tried just about everything I can think of. Looked through this forum and have found nothing that will get the JSON parsed. I am assuming the POST was successful because I am not getting any errors from Order Desk's admin panel.

Order Desk has this code for security purposes. The POST seemed to pass all of them.

```
<?php
//Check For Order
if (!isset($_POST['order'])) {
    header(':', true, 400);
    die('No Data Found');
}

//Cbeck Store ID
//Be sure to set your store ID. Ask Order Desk support if you aren't sure    what it is.
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORDER_DESK_STORE_ID']) ||   $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORDER_DESK_STORE_ID'] != "YOUR-STORE-ID") {
    header(':', true, 403);
    die('Unauthorized Request');
}

//Check the Hash (optional)
//The API Key can be found in the Advanced Settings section. Order Desk Pro only
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORDER_DESK_HASH']) || hash_hmac('sha256', rawurldecode($_POST['order']), 'YOUR_API_KEY') != $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORDER_DESK_HASH']) {
    header(':', true, 403);
    die('Unauthorized Request');
}

//Check Order Data
$order = json_decode($_POST['order'], 1);
if (!is_array($order)) {
    header(':', true, 400);
    die('Invalid Order Data');
}

//Everything Checks Out -- do your thing
echo "<pre>" . print_r($order, 1) . "</pre>";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I guess I am asking how you would parse:

```
$order = json_decode($_POST['order'], 1);
```

What I get from requestb.in :

**FORM/POST PARAMETERS**

```
order: {"id":"1191583","email":"office@burntimpressions.com","shipping_method":"","quantity_total":1,"weight_total":0,"product_total":0,"shipping_total":0,"handling_total":0,"tax_total":0,"discount_total":0,"order_total":0,"cc_number_masked":"","cc_exp":"","processor_response":"","payment_type":"","payment_status":"Approved","processor_balance":0,"customer_id":"","email_count":"1","ip_address":"71.161.83.59","tag_color":"","source_name":"Order Desk","source_id":"1191583","fulfillment_name":"","fulfillment_id":"","tag_name":"","folder_id":6814,"date_added":"2015-06-14 16:53:54","date_updated":"2015-06-14 16:54:27","shipping":{"first_name":"Galen","last_name":"Dively","company":"Vermont Novelty Toaster Corporation","address1":"136 Bay Street","address2":"Ste 2","address3":"","address4":"","city":"Saint Johnsbury","state":"Vermont","postal_code":"05819","country":"US","phone":"(916) 448-5517"},"customer":{"first_name":"Galen","last_name":"Dively","company":"Vermont Novelty Toaster Corporation","address1":"136 Bay Street","address2":"Ste 2","city":"Saint Johnsbury","state":"Vermont","postal_code":"05819","country":"US","phone":"(916) 448-5517"},"checkout_data":[],"order_metadata":[],"discount_list":[],"order_notes":[],"order_items":[{"id":"2090400","name":"selfie test","price":0,"quantity":1,"weight":0,"code":"selfie","delivery_type":"ship","category_code":"","variation_list":[],"metadata":[]}],"order_shipments":[]}
```

**HEADERS**

```
Total-Route-Time: 0
Connect-Time: 1
X-Request-Id: 26eb3b73-bd15-4d75-9605-ea4fda0191dd
User-Agent: Guzzle/5.3.0 curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.5.21
X-Order-Desk-Store-Id: XXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close
Content-Length: 2228
Via: 1.1 vegur
Host: requestb.in
X-Order-Desk-Hash: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: The json which being posted maybe have wrong syntax thats why json decode not work try `echo json_last_error_msg();`

Comment: what does the 1 mean?

Comment: You tried json_last_error or json_last_error_msg ? I updated my comment try json_last_error_msg

Comment: I actually set a switch for all errors last night and was not getting any. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I just setup an API GET to Order Desk. When I switched the 1 in $order = json_decode($_POST['order'], 1); to true, I was able to parse the response. had to ad [order] before [id] to  $transactionId = $order [id];. With the POST from Order Desk it does not work any way I try it

Comment: I am about ready to just do a work around with the API GET, but that would involved two extra steps with the admin back end I am creating for our custom orders. I would much rather have Order Desk POST me the JSON after an order is created or updated.